# IE9 gradient + image

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I want to use the `filter` CSS property for both a gradient and an image. I found and tried something like the following:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='/Controls/Calendar/Events/email.png'), progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#D9D9D9', endColorstr='#989898',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

the problem is that only 1st part of the filter applies. Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Microsoft Developer Network](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#CSS_Filters), you can "apply multiple filters", by separating them with spaces.

Using the following code (no comma between the two filters) should work:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='/Controls/Calendar/Events/email.png') progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#D9D9D9', endColorstr='#989898',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

Comment: Miraculously on a plain html it works with comma also but when transferred on the project it does not. Thank you!