# Using Filters to achieve Gradient Overlay on Background Image in IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I am currently trying to create a gradient overlay on a background image loaded from a URL. I've got this working in most major browsers by using

```
background: linear-gradient(rgba(54, 91, 162, 0.66), rgba(78, 150, 231, 0.66)), url(<urlHere>);
```

Now I know that IE9 does not support CSS Gradient, but it does however support the Filter property, which allows for both Image Loading and Gradients. Now according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11030759/ie9-gradient-image) StackOverflow post along with the [Microsoft Developer Network](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847(v=vs.85).aspx#CSS_Filters) you can have multiple filters by separating them with a `space`. So I tried to make my IE9 filter like so

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#a8365ba2', EndColorStr='#a84e96e7') progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='<urlHere>');
```

However I cannot seem to get this to work correctly in IE9, it will always display just the Background Image without any gradient at all, even if I reverse the order of them in the filter.

I have tested the gradient filter by itself and I know that it works, I have also tested the Background Image filter by itself and can confirm it works too.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `background-image: url()` and `:before/:after` for gradient.

Comment: IE11 has group policy setting for support of legacy dx filters. Use the emulation tab of dev tool to find out which emulation mode the domain is using and how it was established. Use GPO to turn on DX filter support in legacy intranet sites that use Enterprise Site Mode lists or update your intranet sites to html5 and css3 standards.